# The Liouville equation and the BBGKY hierarchy.

Tags: statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism

The [Liouville equation of motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(Hamiltonian)) is written in terms of an $N$ particle distribution $f_N$. 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f_N}{\partial t}=\{H,f_N\}
\end{equation}
Where $\{\cdot ,\cdot \}$ is the [Poisson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) and $f_N=f_N(q_1,\dots ,q_N,p_1,\dots ,p_N)$. Let us now define an $n$ particle probability distribution function $f_n$ with $n< N$. 
\begin{equation}
f _n(q_1,\dots,q_n,p_1,\dots ,p_n,t)=\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\int \prod ^N_{i=n+1}d q^id p_if_{N+1}( q_1,\dots ,q_{N+1},p_1 ,\dots,p_{N+1},t)
\end{equation}
Now $f_n$ satisfies,
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f _n}{\partial t}=\{H_n,f_n\}+\sum ^n_{i=1}\int dq_{n+1}dp_{n+1}\frac{\partial U(q_i-q_{n+1})}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial f _{n+1}}{\partial p_i}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (*)
\end{equation}
With the $n$-body Hamiltonian $H_n$,
\begin{equation}
H_n=\sum ^n_{i=1}\bigg(\frac{p_i^2}{2m}+U(q_i)\bigg)+\sum _{i<j\leq n}U(q_{ij})
\end{equation}
And $q_{ij}=q_i-q_j$. Here $(*)$ is the [BBGKY hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBGKY_hierarchy). I am reading out of the following [notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/kintheory/two.pdf).

Despite reading the linked notes and wikipedia pages etc I am struggling to understand how the BBGKY hierarchy is related to the Liouville equation. In particular taking $n=N$ does not (to my naive understanding) regenerate the Liouville equation. Why do we not require $f_{N+1}$ in the Liouville equation by the logic of the $n$ particle distribution function? Lastly is the Boltzmann equation defined for $f_N$ or $f_1$ (or is it irrelevant, the equation holding in any case?).

Any help on the BBGKY formalism is appreciated so much!

Comment: May be relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149559

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Liouville equation for the $N$ particle system, describes the time evolution of the phase space N-particle probability density, which you can also neatly rewrite with the Liouville operator: $f^{N}(t)= e^{-iLt}f^{N}(0).$ Now almost always we're interested in a smaller subset of only $n$ particles, for which then we have to define a *reduced* phase space distribution function, obtained by integrating out the remaining degrees of freedom ($6(N-n)).$ So the reduced $f^n$ has the form:
$$
f^n (\mathbf{r}^n,\mathbf{p}^n,t) = \frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\int f^N(\mathbf{r}^N,\mathbf{p}^N,t)d\mathbf{r}^{N-n}d\mathbf{p}^{N-n}
$$ 
For our purposes here, to derive an equation of motion for $f^n,$ let's consider a simpler general Hamiltonian:
$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial \mathbf{r}_i}=-\mathbf{X}_i-\sum_{j=1}^{N}\mathbf{F}_{ij}
$$
With $\mathbf{X}$ denotes the external forces due to an external field and $\mathbf{F}_{ij}$ a pairwise interparticle interaction. Inserting into the Liouville equation, for $f^N,$ with a slight rearrangement:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\mathbf{p}_i}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_i}+\sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{X}_i\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i}\right)f^N=-\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\mathbf{F}_{ij}\frac{\partial f^N}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i}
$$
Now by integrating out the unwanted $6(N-n)$ degrees of freedome, we obtain:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\mathbf{p}_i}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_i}+\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{X}_i\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i}\right)f^n=-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbf{F}_{ij}\frac{\partial f^n}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i}- \underbrace{\frac{N!}{(N-n)!}\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=n+1}^N \iint \mathbf{F}_{ij} \frac{\partial f^N}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i} d\mathbf{r}^{N-n}}_{(*)}
d\mathbf{p}^{N-n}
$$
Notice that all the terms with $i>n$ have vanished, to ensure a valid density function $f^n$ for the subspace. Working with identical particles here, we know $f^N$ is symmetric w.r.t. interchange of individual particle labels and the second sum in $(*)$ from $n+1$ to $N$ can be replaced by $N-n$ times the value of any one term (identical particles). With this simplification we can re-write the above equation as:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\mathbf{p}_i}{m}\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{r}_i}+\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\mathbf{X}_i +\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbf{F}_{ij}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i}\right)f^n=-\sum_{i=1}^n \iint \mathbf{F}_{i,n+1} \frac{\partial f^{n+1}}{\partial \mathbf{p}_i} d\mathbf{r}_{n+1}
d\mathbf{p}_{n+1}
$$
We have derived the BBGKY hierarchy, for a relatively less general Hamiltonian. But note that it is an *exact* expression as it stands, linking the one particle phase space density to the two particle density which itself linked the three particle...all the way up to the N particle phase space density. Although such expression doesn't lend itself to much use in practice (for one thing, we don't know any of the $f^n$'s), it can become useful by providing some form of a closure relation, in other words without a closure relation, all BBGKY does is: expresses one unknown density function $f^n$ in terms of another unknown $f^{n+1}.$ It does not however represent an equivalent formulation of the Liouville equation for $f^N$ when you set $n=N$, it only gives you a link with the density function of subspaces of N, which you still don't know. If no closure is provided, BBGKY is not really useful! Have a look at the book of [JP Hansen and IR McDonald](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0123870321) for a more in depth coverage.

Comment: Brilliant answer! One quick follow up question, what is a closure relation?

Comment: @RedPen A closure relation would be one that removes the recursion in BBGKY, such that $f^n$ can be defined in terms of another function $g^n$ of the same subspace. To get yourself acquainted with such relations, have a look at the Hypernetted Chain Approximation which is a closure to the Ornstein-Zernicke relation, which relates the total correlation function to the direct corr. function such that we can eliminate one of the functions and define the other.

Comment: @RedPen I answered a question about a simple closure relation some time ago, which you may or may not find useful: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149561/

Comment: @alarge Thank you very much alarge, both your answers were extremely helpful indeed! I have asked a general question about how to use such formula here    http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/35633/what-closure-relations-can-we-use-in-molecular-modelling